# MySQL UPDATE statement with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute an UPDATE statement as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET goal_seq = 'xyz'
WHERE league_id = 20
AND home = 0
AND away = 0;
```

In trying to work out why it wasnt working I have established that you cant have multiple WHERE clauses (is that correct?) but I cant figure out how to get round it.

Any help much appreciated,

P

Comment: what error are you getting? Btw, TABLE is a reserved word.

Comment: you can have multiple where clauses. Try doing a SELECT first to see if any records actually match your clauses.

Comment: Updated so it doesnt just say table

Comment: Can you please some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

you **CAN** have multiply conditions after WHERE statement - go to [Mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more information and some examples - i believe the key `table` in your code is just a replacement for actual table name? If this query doesn't work pls provide the error which server returns - without it we cannot help you.